# Как правильно организовать функционал активации темы Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Доброго времени суток, друзья.

Хочу протестировать продажи русскоязычных тем для Wordpress копиями, а не под заказ. Собственно, тема готова, осталось организовать функционал активации темы - нужно сделать так, чтобы одну тему можно было активировать только на двух доменах.

Подскажите, как правильно организовать все и в какую сторону копать вообще. Я думал, сделать так:
- у себя на сервере в БД сделать табличку, записывать туда уникальные ключи активации + 2 домена;
- при активации темы покупателем, на специальной странице нужно ввести ключ активации и этот ключ должен быть уникальным в табличке БД, а если это не так, то все файлы темы тут же удалить у нечестного покупателя.

Только как это все правильно сделать, ткните носом, пожалуйста :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так примерно и делают. Только вот удалять не надо. Мало ли - ошибся человек, а вы ему сайт сломали. Он и в суд может подать. Ограничьте функционал, если ключ не тот. Например, запретите обновления.

Только все равно же хакнут вашу тему, если захотят. Как защитить код, если он весь целиком передается покупателю? Да никак).

Поэтому в коммерческих темах никакой защиты и нет. Купил тему - можешь ставить куда угодно. Продавцы понимают бесплодность всех попыток защитить код в исходниках и просто не занимаются этим.

Да и логика жизни подсказывает - ну не будет покупатель ставить одну и ту же тему на 10 сайтов - скучно. И уж тем более не будет ее дарить кому-то, раз деньги заплатил.

Comment: Согласен :) Но все равно хочется хоть какую-то защиту придумать.

Comment: @G_Java дурное занятие. Лучше развивать продукт, чтобы его хотелось купить. А это получается у 0,001% желающих заработать таким вот образом. Чтобы кому-то захотелось использовать (даже не купить) тема(ы)-разработчик должны пройти популярность в репо. А так.. нафик никому не нужны платные продукты незнамокого.